# MySQL script gives me random errors

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

I have been trying to create a very simple MySQL script

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Test

BEGIN
    
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;

    WHILE counter <= 10 DO
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END WHILE;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And it keeps giving me errors at random places like for example :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE counter <= 10 DO
        SET counter = counter + 1' at line 1
```

Coming from SQL server, I don't really understand what the issue could be. I am using DBeaver.
MySQL version :

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.29 for macos12.2 on arm64 (Homebrew)
```

Comment: With "random", you don't mean the error changes every time, do you?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do... If I try to re-run the script, it moves. For example, it is now located here : "DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;"

Comment: Interesting... It all points to a bug in DBeaver then. I could be helpful to determine if this happens in the official command-line client. (I don't have MySQL at hand to test it myself.)

Comment: It is indeed a DBeaver issue... The script worked fine in the SQL prompt.

Comment: Your `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement also fails in MySQL command line because it's missing the parameter block after the name. Brackets are mandatory even if you don't have parameters ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)). If you fix that, it runs correctly in command-line. If the code is not correct, it may not be strange that it clashes with DBeaver SQL parser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DBeaver issue with query and new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162823/dbeaver-issue-with-query-and-new-line)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

> Actually it is not a bug.
> DBeaver has two modes of SQL execution: statement (CTRL+Enter) and script (ALT+X).
> In statement mode it extracts current statement (it is statement where cursor is positioned and it is delimited by empty lines or by ";" symbol). It allows you to have many SQL statements in a single SQL editor and execute any of them at any time. It is very convinient if many cases. Empty line as statement delimiter is very native and visual way to structurize text.
> Also you may select any part of SQL text and press CTRL+Enter - dbeaver will execute only selected text.
>
> In script mode dbeaver executes entire SQL script. It will split script on statements using ";" symbol (empty lines have no meaning in this mode) and then execute them one by one.
>
> So, if you want to execute single statement which contains empty line you have to select this statement and press CTRL+Enter.
>
> Probably we can somehow improve SQL execution. But at the moment I don't have any good ideas about it.
> Serge

https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=669

So I ran a similar script that had the same issue and it then worked.