# DBeaver issue with query and new line

Tags: sql, dbeaver

When I'm trying to run a query with some newline, DBeaver always gives me an error:

```
Errore SQL [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword ....
```

What's the problem? What can I do?
This is an example of query:

```
    select * from table2

    inner join table3 on idtable2 = idtable3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found the way. DBeaver simply consider the newline/breakline as a statement separator.

But there is a way to remove this option in `Editor > Editor SQL > SQL Processing`

[image: Options]

Credit: [Link](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/5025#issuecomment-475325807)